# Rails create and update array in database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

So I have a service object that submits up votes and voted users into a database:

Here's the posts model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment_count, :downvote, :id, :text, :title, :upvote, :url, :user_id, :users_voted_up_by, :users_voted_down_by

  serialize :users_voted_up_by, Array
  serialize :users_voted_down_by, Array

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here's the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username, :good_karma, :bad_karma, :posts_voted_up_on, :posts_voted_down_on

  serialize :posts_voted_up_on, Array
  serialize :posts_voted_down_on, Array

  has_many :posts

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

Now here's my Voter class that controls up votes and down votes.

```
class Voter
  def initialize(post, user)
    @post = post
    @user = user
  end

  def upvote
    return false unless @post.users_voted_up_by
    @post.upvote += 1
    @post.users_voted_up_by << @user.username
    @user.good_karma += 1
    @post.save && @user.save
  end

  def downvote
    return false unless @post.users_voted_down_by
    @post.upvote += 1
    @post.users_voted_down_by << @user.username
    @user.bad_karma += 1
    @post.save && @user.save
  end
end
```

It adds and retrevies the first one fine:

User1

But when I perform another "upvote" with a different user, instead of adding it to the array it just adds it to the string like this:

User1User2

Am I not using the line correctly?

`@post.users_voted_up_by << @user.username`

Comment: It would help if we could see the model relationships in this instance

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just the `to_s` method. What does `@post.users_voted_up_by.join(', ')` produce?

Comment: Undefined method "join". It's not just .to_s, serialize stores the integrity of the array in the database, or it should, I don't think I'm using it correctly. I need an example, but can't find one.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to model a many-to-many relationship via serialized arrays. In my opinion this is a misuse of Rails serialization feature.

The more appropriate way to design your problem is to create a Vote model which belongs to User and has one Post. It is better both in design perspective and db-performance perspective.

Once you do that you won't add users to a post votes array, you will just create a new Vote instance with the voter (user) id and the post id.

Comment: Wont' that table quickly become massive? Have have a third table with thousands of rows when you can have 3 more columns that contain an integer.

Comment: It will become massive but thanks to today's modern SQL engines and good indices on the right columns queries on that table will be very fast.

Comment: Do I need a controller for this Vote model as well?

Comment: No controller needed. It would just be a more solid design.

Comment: I'd definitely create a VotesController to handle all vote operations.

Comment: @freakyDaz How do I create a link_to to these actions? Could you possibly outline the pieces that go into creating this custom model and making a link_to that I can pass the post, current user, and 'up' or 'down' boolean to? Thanks.